# Preventing duplicate views from being added to list adapter

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with the code [SOLVED THX ALL]

```
private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        ChatView chatvieww = new ChatView();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);
            chatvieww.setCodigo(json.getString(ChatViewUtils.TAG_CODIGO));
            chatvieww.setUsername(json.getString(ChatViewUtils.TAG_USERCHAT));
            chatvieww.setMensagem(json.getString(ChatViewUtils.TAG_MENSAGEM));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (chatview.size() > 1) {
            if (!chatview.get(i).getId().equals(chatview.get(i-1).getId())) {
                chatview.add(chatvieww);
            }
        } else {
            this.chatview.add(chatvieww);
        }
    }
    //Notifying the adapter that data has been added or changed
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I have error at,

`if (!chatview.get(i).getId().equals(chatview.get(i-1).getId()))`

how to resolve the problem?

This is my `Logcat`,

```
09-02 10:22:21.163 8263-8263/pet.com.br.pet E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
          Process: pet.com.br.pet, PID: 8263
          java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
              at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
              at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
              at pet.com.br.pet.chat.ChatViewActivity.parseData(ChatViewActivity.java:165)
```

chatview 
    public class ChatView {
    private String id;...

Comment: You should post some more info about that error.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: In your code, you should probably use index i-1 instead of i. You have `!chatview.get(i).getId().equals(chatview.get(i).getId())` in your code, but below you have `!chatview.get(i).getId().equals(chatview.get(i-1).getId())`. So your condition always evaluates to false.

Comment: the error persist i have updated the question

Comment: Where is the `chartview` list variable defined? You probably do not want to access it by `i` because that is the size of the JSON Array.

Comment: look I have updated the question

Comment: public class ChatView {

    private String id;
    private String username;
    private String codigo;
    private String mensagem;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

Answer (score 1):

Don't know which container you are using for chatview. But you could write something like that:

```
private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
    Set<String> current_ids = new HashSet<String>();
    //cache current ids
    for(ChatView current : chatveiww) {
        current_ids.add(current.getId());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        ChatView newView = new ChatView();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);
            newView.setId(json.getString(ChatViewUtils.TAG_ID));
            newView.setCodigo(json.getString(ChatViewUtils.TAG_CODIGO));
            newView.setUsername(json.getString(ChatViewUtils.TAG_USERCHAT));
            newView.setMensagem(json.getString(ChatViewUtils.TAG_MENSAGEM));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (current_ids.contains(newView.getId()) {
            //skip duplicate item
            continue;
        }

        current_ids.add(newView.getId());            
        chatview.add(newView);
    }
    //Notifying the adapter that data has been added or changed
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This could be optimized depending on what container are you using and if `ID` could be converted to integer value

But to make it even better update your ChatView to look like :

```
class ChatView {
    private String mID; //the id string

    /*** Your rest code***/

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        ChatView other = (ChatView) o;

        return !(mID != null ? !mID.equals(other.mID) : other.mID != null);    
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return mID != null ? mID.hashCode() : 0;
    }
}
```

Now You can store your `ChatView` items in `HashSet` or in `LinkedHashSet` (if you need to preserve order) and parseData become simpler:

```
private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        ChatView newView = new ChatView();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);
            newView.setId(json.getString(ChatViewUtils.TAG_ID));
            newView.setCodigo(json.getString(ChatViewUtils.TAG_CODIGO));
            newView.setUsername(json.getString(ChatViewUtils.TAG_USERCHAT));
            newView.setMensagem(json.getString(ChatViewUtils.TAG_MENSAGEM));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (chatview.contains(newView) {
            //skip duplicate item
            continue;
        }

        chatview.add(newView);
    }
    //Notifying the adapter that data has been added or changed
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        ChatView chatvieww = new ChatView();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);
            chatvieww.setId(json.getString(ChatViewUtils.TAG_ID));
            chatvieww.setCodigo(json.getString(ChatViewUtils.TAG_CODIGO));
            chatvieww.setUsername(json.getString(ChatViewUtils.TAG_USERCHAT));
            chatvieww.setMensagem(json.getString(ChatViewUtils.TAG_MENSAGEM));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Linear search, see if the id exists
        boolean flag = false;
        for(ChatView chat : chatview){ 
            if(null != chat.getId() && null != chatvieww.getId()){
                if(chat.getId().equals(chatvieww.getId())){
                    // Item exists
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // if flag is true item exists, don't add.
        if(!flag){
            chatview.add(chatvieww);
        }
    }
    // Notifying the adapter that data has been added or changed
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: 09-02 10:34:51.473 15125-15125/pet.com.br.pet E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: pet.com.br.pet, PID: 15125
                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                                                                    at pet.com.br.pet.chat.ChatViewActivity.parseData(ChatViewActivity.java:167)

Comment: It is generating and the information still duplicated LOOP

Comment: you have any idea?

Comment: it is working but remove all messages any idea to compare actual id to the id-1? and return the not duplicated id?

Comment: What do you mean by `id-1` and return where?

Comment: the code should generate check the server items if the ID is not the same as the predecessor of the current position id in the array

Comment: What if the position id is 0?

Comment: it adds the first id to compare to the id 0

Comment: if(chatview.size()==0){chatview.add(chatvieww);
}else if(ifchatview.size() >= 1)...